# How to query on a BsonDocument in C# mongodb

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have collection of document with an array for documents in it.

I am able to query the sub documents in C# separately. But this will hit the database server again.

But in my case I am initially querying and getting the document. But after that I need to re query on this document without hitting the database again.

Does anyone know how to query the BsonDocument(Not Collection) in C#.

Thanks for your help in advance.
-Nitin Jain

Answer (score 0):

You can't use any of the query capabilities of MongoDb locally on the client. The logic for the query engine is entirely on the Database server.

You'll need to write code in C# to query the objects. If they were strongly typed objects rather than a BSON document, you could easily use LINQ with the document objects and have a similar experience on the client (of course, it wouldn't have features such as indexes available).